# Self-extracting web environment

Tags: php, ruby, apache, zip

Basically I have two applications:

- a PHP web application that runs over Apache and Mysql
- a ruby application that has been built with gem dependencies

What I would like to be able to create is a self extracting archive; once all the files have been extracted into any directory, my users can just click two bat files:

- the first one configures and runs Apache and Mysql + deploy my PHP application
- the second one runs my ruby application

Is it possible to do that? if yes, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should take a look at [InstantRails](http://rubyforge.org/frs/?group_id=904). The package is an archive of the Windows Ruby distribution that includes Ruby 1.8, RoR 2, MySQL, Apache, PHP, and PHPmyadmin.  It is a fairly large archive, but it looks to have everything that you need for your project.  It is a bit behind in it's rails distribution, but can be updated with a 'gem update' statement.